# Best way to remove elements in list based on string pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a table (list of lists). An example output being the following:

```
table = ['dd03', 'ff0000', 'a30b32', '000000', '234fas', '00ffff', 'ffffff', '0000ff', '0200ff']
```

I want to remove all elements in the list that have any combinations of 'ff' in them or atleast 2/6 chars in the element being of that character.

I've done a list comprehension which does the job but it's clearly not very efficient and could surely be done with less code.

```
    table = [[part for part in my_list if part != 'ffffff'] for my_list in table]
    table = [[part for part in my_list if part != 'ffff00'] for my_list in table]
    table = [[part for part in my_list if part != 'ff0000'] for my_list in table]
    table = [[part for part in my_list if part != '0000ff'] for my_list in table]
    table = [[part for part in my_list if part != '00ffff'] for my_list in table]
    table = [[part for part in my_list if part != 'ffff'] for my_list in table]
    table = [[part for part in my_list if part != 'ff'] for my_list in table]
    table = [[part for part in my_list if part != 'ffff02'] for my_list in table]
    table = [[part for part in my_list if part != '0200ff'] for my_list in table]
```

I thought maybe set a regex variable for the pattern to find and then remove elements that match... but I'm not too familiar with this package and implementing it in this case.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Change the `if` condition to: `if 'ff' not in part`

Comment: Could you explain the 2/6th condition clearer? Why can't you just count how many times `f` appears in each string?

Comment: `'f34fas'` would that count as having 2/6ths `'f'`s?

Comment: So far, all the answers are wrong. Until the OP makes the question clear, no one should be answering. Answers that guess at the OP's intentions just create noise when the question gets properly specified and answered.

Answer (score 9):

A simple containment check should work:

```
[item for item in table if 'ff' not in item]
```

The 'atleast 2/6' condition is quite redundant (the length is a constant 6), enough to check if item does not contain `'ff'`.

Comment: OP might mean that the `'f'`s might not be together by the 2/6 rule.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I doubt that, a good look at their code tells they are together

Comment: If anything, the `ff` condition is the redundant one. And the length is not constant.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the elements without `ff` like this,

```
In [29]: print [i for i in table if 'ff' not in i]
['dd03', 'a30b32', '000000', '234fas']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
table = ['dd03', 'ff0000', 'a30b32', '000000', '234fas', '00ffff', 'ffffff', '0000ff', '0200ff']
filtered_table = [item for item in table if item.count('f') < 2]
```

Comment: As not all of the strings are of the same length, just checking if there are two or more `f`s is not sufficient.

Comment: @pzp Do you mean it should be `if item.count('f') / len(item) < 1/3`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, although It should really be `if len(item) > 3 * item.count('f')` to avoid floating point division problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the elements of the list and pop() those who include the sub-string:

```
for item in list_of_items:
    if "ff" in item:
        list_of_items.pop(list_of_items.index(item))
```